# Should i use SOAP or REST in accessing Web service?

Tags: android, json, web-services, soap

i want to access a java web service Running on a Server. which one SOAP or JSON is good to access this web service. i dont want to put overhead on the Server and want the calling of web service to be Fast. plz suggest better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON and SOAP are two different things. JSON is just a data format while SOAP act as Manager on server side that manage request and response from client.. it can return JSON as a result which is a data format likehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382864/answer/submit XML

Answer (score 0):

You do not access a Web Service with JSON, that is just a format. Depending on the Web Service you might need to communicate with it by sending SOAP envelopes or using REST.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is a lot of confusion here.  SOAP/REST are two approaches to managing services ON THE SERVER SIDE.  SOAP is XML-based, while REST is URL based.  Assuming you are writing an Android app, you won't be implementing the SOAP/REST/WSDL interfaces-- you will get them from the service team.

So, if the web service you are using provides both REST and SOAP, then you can choose which set of endpoints to hit.

When you are packaging up your request and sending it to the service, you probably want to package it as JSON.  JSON is just "Object Notation."  Inherently, it is nothing more than a way to format data in such a way it universally recognized.  Alternatively, you can package your request as XML.  But JSON is more light-weight, as XML has a lot of required redundancy (unless it is compressed).

Comment: can u tell me whether should i use RESTless or RESTfull java web service to access in Android. which one is better and efficient in terms of simplicity and speed.

Comment: RESTful is going to be the easiest.  It is all URL based-- for example, to add a user:  `www.mysite.com/addUser` and if you want to edit users, hit: `www.mysite.com/edituser`  etc.  I can't explain it all here, so I would suggest googling for `Android REST sample`